# Проблема с PHP кодом и базой данных MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean
>   given in
>   D:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\test.ru\apparates\poddomens\otzyvy.php on
>   line 46
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in
>   D:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\test.ru\apparates\poddomens\otzyvy.php on
>   line 48

Выдает такую ошибку почему понять не могу

Вот мой код:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете процедурный стиль при работе с mysqli. Соответственно, рулит [документация и примеры](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php).

Вот пример с оф.сайта:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if (!$link) {
    die('Ошибка подключения (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Сообщение об ошибке

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in D:\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\test.ru\apparates\poddomens\otzyvy.php on line 46

явно указывает на тот факт, что соединение с базой создано не было (или как минимум переменная содержит логическое значение), и функция `mysqli_connect` вернула `FALSE`. Так что все нотайсы и ерроры - *следствие*. Причина - нет коннекта к базе. Проверьте перед вызовом mysqli_query соединение на ошибки, а переменную на предмет содержания ресурса.

P.S. Детально просмотрел Ваш второй скриншот. Вы проводите инициализацию массива, содержащего конфигурацию для подключения к базе, ПОСЛЕ его использования. Т.е. в момент использования переменная $config не инициализирована и ее значение равно NULL. В логе php должно быть об этом сообщение.

Comment: Я не знаю, почему к базе данных не подключается вообще никак, про $config я и так и так делал, тщетно, не знаю что делать вообще

Answer (score -1):

вот что не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так же мой код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Редактируйте свой вопрос, а не создавайте ответ, если текст не содержит ответ. Вставляйте текст, а не картинку.

Comment: "Не так" то, что пользователь root не мог зайти в базу с тем паролем, который Вы используете. То ли пароль не верный, то ли прав на данную конкретную базу у рута нет. Проверьте это, запустив консольную утилиту и зайдя на сервер mysql: `mysql -u root -p` и введите пароль в ответ на приглашение, затем откройте базу, используя команду `use comments`. Если на сервер зашли, а в базу - нет, значит проблема с правами. Если на сервер не зашли - значит проблема с паролем.